# Xamarin Mac NSScrollView with dynamic content

Tags: macos, xamarin, dynamic, nsscrollview, xamarin.mac

I want to add a unknown count of **Custom Views** to a **NSScrollView** within a **Xamarin Mac** application, but I cannot find a way to do this. On iOS I would create a UIScrollView containing a UIView containing a UIStackView which will automatically layout the controls.

I tried it like this:

```
var controller = (AudioViewController)Storyboard.InstantiateControllerWithIdentifier("AudioView");
var subview = controller.View;
stvFiles.AddArrangedSubview(subview);
```

the first view will be displayed, but needs the whole space, and the second view will not be visible.

How would one do it adding dynamically views to a **NSScrollView**?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

For everyone having the same problem, here is a [**solution**](https://github.com/mattiasjahnke/NSStackView-Scroll) i found.
It was coded with Swift, but implementing it in C# is easy.